# i installed linux 12.04 and when i login the desktop is frozen

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, wubi

Hi I recently installed Linux Ubuntu 12.04 via wubi. I did everything correctly and when the boot screen loads up I select Ubuntu and it shows the log in screen and i log in to my account and once I'm logged in I can see my desktop but I cant see the task bar where it shows the time and battery etc. and my mouse. **Also the screen is frozen and I can't control nor do anything**. Here our my specs below

**Windows 7 64 bit
6GBS of DDR2 Ram
NVIDIA Geforce 620 2 GBS
AMD Athlon II X2 235e Dual Core
With 750GBS on hard drive C: and 500GB on hard drive B:**

**Please help I would love to use Ubuntu. Thanks       * EDIT EDIT * I just installed Ubuntu and the WHOLE DESKTOP is frozen I cannot move or open or do anything it is completely frozen***

Answer (score 0):

can u explain more briefly...what is wish to know that.....whether only the mouse and keyboard are not working .....or.......the whole system s frozen....

if its the mouse and keyboard unplug and plug back.....

but if the second case check this link:

[What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: The whole desktop is frozen i cannot do anything